# How to get a slice of tuples (hour, minute)

Tags: datetime, go, time, tuples, slice

I've got a problem that I couldn't resolve. I'm using https://github.com/kmanley/golang-tuple to create tuples.

I've got a list of minutes:

```
minutes := int{0, 30} // Minutes are 0 and 30
```

And a four parameters: `start`, `startBreak`, `stop`, `stopBreak`:

```
start := tuple.NewTupleFromItems(9, 30) // It represents "9:30"
startBreak := tuple.NewTupleFromItems(12, 0) // It represents "12:00"
stop := tuple.NewTupleFromItems(21, 0) // It represents "21:00"
stopBreak := tuple.NewTupleFromItems(14, 30) // It represents "14:30"
```

I want to get a slice of tuples `(hour, minutes)` using all the minutes in the `minutes` slice and they must not be included in the range `startBreak-stopBreak` (it can be equal to `startBreak` or `stopBreak`, so the range will become `12:30, 13:00, 13:30, 14:00`) and `stop-start` (it can be equal to `start` and `stop`, so the range will become `21:30, 22:00, 22:30, ..., 8:30, 9:00`).

For example, using those four parameters, the final result will be:

```
9:30, 10:00, 10:30, 11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 14:30, 15:00, 15:30, 16:00, 16:30, 17:00, 17:30, 18:00, 18:30, 19:00, 19:30, 20:00, 20:30, 21:00
```

Comment: I would suggest you put which part of your code you are having trouble from.

Comment: @ssemilla You're right. I'll do next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal code that demonstrates this, I did not put any data validation.

```
func periods(minutes, start, startBreak, stopBreak, stop *tuple.Tuple) (out []tuple.Tuple) {

    // next() moves current to the next minute interval
    i := 0
    curr := tuple.NewTupleFromItems(start.Get(0), minutes.Get(0))
    next := func() {
        i = (i + 1) % minutes.Len()
        curr.Set(1, minutes.Get(i))
        if i == 0 {
            curr.Set(0, curr.Get(0).(int)+1)
        }
    }

    for ; curr.Le(stop); next() {
        if (curr.Ge(start) && curr.Le(startBreak)) || (curr.Ge(stopBreak) && curr.Le(stop)) {
            out = append(out, *curr.Copy())
        }
    }

    return out
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zSEut6KUziX)